# after_commit for an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using an after_commit in my application.

I would like it to trigger only when a particular field is updated in my model. Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 77):

Old question, but this is one method that I've found that might work with the after_commit callback (working off [paukul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14732669/403664)). At least, the values both persist post-commit in IRB.

```
after_commit :callback, 
  if: proc { |record| 
    record.previous_changes.key?(:attribute) &&
      record.previous_changes[:attribute].first != record.previous_changes[:attribute].last
  }
```

Comment: Based on [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Dirty/previous_changes), I think `keys` must be called: `record.previous_changes.keys.include?(:attribute)`. With this change, it works for me.

Comment: `record.previous_changes.key?(:attribute)` is sufficient condition, because first and last values are always not equal.

Comment: @jamesdevar is right, but this solution can fail if your model is saved more than once during the transaction.  Here is a sample Rails project https://github.com/ccmcbeck/after-commit to demonstrate the problem and the my solution to fix it.

Comment: I'm using rails 4.2.7.1. `field_modified?` did not work, this one works for me. Save my life!!!

Comment: For the one that want to check if the record is changed on more than one attribute: `(record.previous_changes.keys & [:list, :of, :attributes]).any?`

Comment: Don't do what I did and accept this answer without first reading Chris Beck's answer further down! `previous_changes` can't be trusted in after_commit and can cause you a lot of trouble if you think it can!

Answer (score 24):

*Answering this old question because it still pops up in search results*

you can use the [previous_changes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-previous_changes) method which returnes a hash of the format:

{ "changed_attribute" => ["old value", "new value"] }

it's what [changes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changes) was until the record gets actually saved (from active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb):

```
  def save(*) #:nodoc:
    if status = super
      @previously_changed = changes
      @changed_attributes.clear
      # .... whatever goes here
```

so in your case you can check for `previous_changes.key? "your_attribute"` or something like that

Answer (score 11):

Old question but still pops up in search results.

As of Rails 5 `attribute_changed?` was deprecated. Using `saved_change_to_attribute?` instead of `attribute_changed?` is recommended.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you can do it in `after_commit`

The after_commit is called after the transaction is commited [Rails Transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html)

For example in my rails console

```
> record = MyModel.find(1)
=> #<MyModel id: 1, label: "test", created_at: "2011-08-19 22:57:54", updated_at: "2011-08-19 22:57:54">
> record.label = "Changing text"
=> "Changing text"
> record.label_changed?
=> true
> record.save
=> true
> record.label_changed?
=> false
```

Therefore you won't be able to use the `:if` condition on `after_commit` because the attribute will not be marked as changed anymore as it has been saved. You may need to track whether the field you are after is `changed?` in another callback before the record is saved?

Answer (score 8):

This is a very old problem, but the accepted `previous_changes` solution just isn't robust enough. In an `ActiveRecord` transaction, there are many reasons why you might save a Model twice. `previous_changes` only reflects the result of the final `save`.  Consider this example

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit: :after_commit_test

  def :after_commit_test
    puts previous_changes.inspect
  end
end

test = Test.create(number: 1, title: "1")
test = Test.find(test.id) # to initialize a fresh object

test.transaction do
  test.update(number: 2)
  test.update(title: "2")
end
```

which outputs:

```
{"title"=>["1", "2"], "updated_at"=>[...]}
```

but, what you need is:

```
{"title"=>["1", "2"], "number"=>[1, 2], "updated_at"=>[...]}
```

So, my solution is this:

```
module TrackSavedChanges
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # expose the details if consumer wants to do more
    attr_reader :saved_changes_history, :saved_changes_unfiltered
    after_initialize :reset_saved_changes
    after_save :track_saved_changes
  end

  # on initalize, but useful for fine grain control
  def reset_saved_changes
    @saved_changes_unfiltered = {}
    @saved_changes_history = []
  end

  # filter out any changes that result in the original value
  def saved_changes
    @saved_changes_unfiltered.reject { |k,v| v[0] == v[1] }
  end

  private

  # on save
  def track_saved_changes
    # maintain an array of ActiveModel::Dirty.changes
    @saved_changes_history << changes.dup
    # accumulate the most recent changes
    @saved_changes_history.last.each_pair { |k, v| track_saved_change k, v }
  end

  # v is an an array of [prev, current]
  def track_saved_change(k, v)
    if @saved_changes_unfiltered.key? k
      @saved_changes_unfiltered[k][1] = track_saved_value v[1]
    else
      @saved_changes_unfiltered[k] = v.dup
    end
  end

  # type safe dup inspred by http://stackoverflow.com/a/20955038
  def track_saved_value(v)
    begin
      v.dup
    rescue TypeError
      v
    end
  end
end
```

which you can try out here: https://github.com/ccmcbeck/after-commit

Comment: +1 for acknowledging this problem, I've run into it multiple times already. I'll take a sniff at your solution to see how well it'll fit my case!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want something like a [conditional callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks). If you had posted some code I could have pointed you in the right direction however I think you would want to use something like this:

```
after_commit :callback,
  :if => Proc.new { |record| record.field_modified? }
```

Comment: is field_modified? a pre-made method or is this a method i'll need to write to check the field value? basically i am trying to recalculate and save a user's rating based on all his appointment ratings. a rating to an appointment may be added after it has been created, so i'd like to know if the rating field was updated

here is some of the code i am working with

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  after_commit :update_user_and_product_ratings
  
  def update_user_and_product_ratings
    self.user.update_rating
    self.product.update_rating
  end

Answer (score 0):

Use gem [ArTransactionChanges](https://github.com/dylanahsmith/ar_transaction_changes). `previous_changes` is not working for me in Rails 4.0.x

Usage:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ArTransactionChanges

  after_commit :print_transaction_changes

  def print_transaction_changes
    transaction_changed_attributes.each do |name, old_value|
      puts "attribute #{name}: #{old_value.inspect} -> #{send(name).inspect}"
    end
  end
end
```