# Rails, using the dirty or changed? flag with after_commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I heard rails has a dirty/change flag. Is it possible to use that in the after_commit callback?

In my user model I have:

```
after_commit :push_changes
```

In `def push_changes` I would like a way to know if the name field changed. Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do a few things to check...

First and foremost, you can check an individual attribute as such:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.name_changed? # => false
user.name = "Bob"
user.name_changed? # => true
```

But, you can also check which attributes have changed in the entire model:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.changed     # => []
user.name = "Bob"
user.age = 42
user.changed     # => ['name', 'age']
```

There's a few more things you can do too - check out http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html for details.

**Edit:**

But, given that this is happening in an `after_commit` callback, the model has already been saved, meaning knowledge of the changes that occurred before the save are lost.  You could try using the `before_save` callback to pick out the changes yourself, store them somewhere, then access them again when using `after_commit`.

Comment: Right, sorry, missed that part of it.  After saving the model the changed attributes are wiped out, so this would be pretty useless...  Could you yourself store the changed attributes using `before_save`, for instance, and then retrieve them afterwards?

Comment: `changed?`/`changes` will work in **after_save**, but not **after_commit**. Instead, you can use `previous_changes` in **after_commit**- see @Jonathan's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16823712/165673)

Answer (score 36):

You can use [previous_changes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-previous_changes) in **after_commit** to access a model's attribute values from before it was saved.

see this post for more info:
[after_commit for an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128073/after-commit-for-an-attribute)

Comment: activerecord is cool, I just had one example of previous_changes - http://t.co/yjCLEdDHYH

Answer (score 4):

Since Rails 5.1, in `after_commit` you should use `saved_change_to_attribute?`

Ref: [Rails 5.1.1 deprecation warning changed_attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634356/rails-5-1-1-deprecation-warning-changed-attributes)