# Rails 5.1.1 deprecation warning changed_attributes

Tags: deprecation-warning, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I've just upgraded from Rails 5.0.0 to 5.1.1 and started getting a ton of deprecation warnings like this:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of `changed_attributes` inside of
>   after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new
>   return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after
>   `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To
>   maintain the current behavior, use
>   `saved_changes.transform_values(&:first)` instead.

and this:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of `attribute_changed?` inside of
>   after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new
>   return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after
>   `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To
>   maintain the current behavior, use `saved_change_to_attribute?`
>   instead.

I don't use those methods explicitely anywhere in my project and the warnings are pointing mostly at create and update calls on my models.

I believe it has something to do with my validations and `after_update` and `after_create` callbacks where I use confitions like `if: { author_id_changed? }` but I have no idea what to do with them.

I also believe the warning is related to [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/16ae3db5a5c6a08383b974ae6c96faac5b4a3c81) massive update to ActiveRecord.

Would appreciate any hand you can give with this.

**UPD**

[This article](http://blog.toshima.ru/2017/04/06/saved-change-to-attribute.html) helped alot!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, got around everything by running `bundle update` and updating the gems and also following [this article](http://blog.toshima.ru/2017/04/06/saved-change-to-attribute.html) and changing `attribute_changed?` calls in `after_` callbacks (but not in `before_` callbacks and `validations`) and switching from `attribute_was` to `attribute_before_last_save`.

Answer (score 8):

For After callbacks, you can use **saved_change_to_attribute?**

For Before callbacks and validations, you can use **will_save_change_to_attribute?**

I hope this information will help!

Comment: `will_save_change_to_attribute` is what i needed for my before callback, thanks

Answer (score 5):

I've done an upgrade to **Rails 5.1.6** and have the same DEPRECATION warnings. If ever anyone still wants to solve this warning. Here are the steps I took:

Search all of your`*_changed?`

Changed this:

```
if name_changed?
...
if user_id_changed?
```

To this if it is inside `after_*` (after_save, after_commit, after_update, etc.) blocks:

```
if saved_change_to_name?
...
if saved_change_to_user_id?
```

AND to this if it is inside `before_*` (before_save, before_commit, before_update, etc.) blocks:

```
if will_save_change_to_name?
...
if will_save_change_to_user_id?
```

On my own opinion, this is quite tricky thing to change since we've been used to `attribute_changed?`. But change is good. The syntax also made more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

You can change `author_id_changed?` to `saved_change_to_author_id?`

Comment: Your answer below is correct for validations.  The version I mentioned doesn't work in validations because the data hasn't actually been saved yet.