# Rails after commit condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my rails model I need to call `after_commit` callback if and only if one of the table attributes is changed from one value to other.
This is working fine with `after_update` callback but I am invoking some additional tasks in the background and `after_commit` is the perfect one for this. Any suggestions?

Sample code

```
    after_commit :call_cli, :if=> :change

    def change  
      if self.status_changed?  
        filename = '/location/res.log'              
        File.open(filename, File::WRONLY) do |file|
          file.write self.status_change_was+"\n"
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: **after_commit** is executing perfectly. But my requirement is such that it should run iff the table attribute changes. Let me give more details.

Comment: **after_commit** is working with out the condition since the self object is destroyed. I am struggling here because I can call CLI if the attribute value is changed. Could you please help me with some sample code.

Comment: I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128073/after-commit-for-an-attribute) about conditional `after_commit`, in case you want to check out some other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Called another callback **before_update** and self.status_changed? value is stored in a flag as **@flag = self.status_changed?**
Thanks to this article - http://axonflux.com/offlining-denormalized-tasks-gotchas-with-off.
Also cheers to **Dave Newton** for the kind help.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a `previous changes` method, which I would recommend: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-previous_changes