# How do I check if a variable really responds_to :dup?

Tags: ruby

I wanted to use `value.respond_to?(:dup) ? value.dup : value` in order to check if I can duplicate an object but it failed with `TypeError` on booleans, nil or such "primitives" alike.

I've ended up with:

```
begin
  value = value.dup
rescue
  #ignore, use the original if no dup-able (e.g nil, true, etc)
end
```

Is there a better way?

Bonus: Why does it responds `:dup`?

Not deep `dup`, just for the question.

**EDIT**:    Thoughts:

- `obj.class.methods.include? :new` is nice but a bit too hackish i think it has bad performance
- `Marshal` also looks like an overkill
- one line rescue could have been the best solution, but type specific one line rescue is not possible at this time ([IIUC matz is on that!](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6739#change-31795)), and as @JörgWMittag mentioned its wrong.
- Personally i think `dup` being defined at the object level is wrong.

So, quoting @Linuxios

> There isn't really a better way

Comment: What is the ruby version you are using? I am on 1.9.3, and `value.respond_to?(:dup)` where value is boolean, returns `false` to me and not a `type error`. Similarly with nils and others.

Comment: FWIW there's an open issue for this, but it hasn't gotten much attention: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11929

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't really a better way. `dup` is defined on Object, which means that any class which wants to not respond to it needs to overload it to throw an exception. `NilClass`, `TrueClass`, `FalseClass`, and `Number` are all subclasses of Object. That means they have to override the method to throw an error.

One way around this, if you are looking for a deep copy anyway, is to use the usual `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(obj))` which will deal with numbers, bools, and nil just fine.

For example:

```
1.9.3-p392 :001 > obj = "hi"
 => "hi"
1.9.3-p392 :002 > Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(obj)).object_id != obj.object_id
 => true
1.9.3-p392 :003 > obj = 3
 => 3
1.9.3-p392 :004 > Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(obj)).object_id != obj.object_id
 => false
```

Comment: and `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(obj)).object_id != obj.object_id` tells you if it's a dup.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Yep, and it is a true deep copy unless `obj` is a number, bool, or nil.

Comment: +1 for using Marshal. It's "hack-ish", but not a hack.

Comment: I guess `Numeric` and `Symbol` go the list too.

Answer (score 6):

You can write it as one line this way:

```
value = value.dup rescue value
```

Very clear.

It is standard to define a `dup` method that raises `TypeError` for types that cannot be duplicated. Thus any object will "respond to" it. You really have to call it and check with a begin-rescue-end.

Comment: You should *never* blindly `rescue` from `StandardError`. You should only handle the most specific exception, in this case `TypeError`.

Answer (score 3):

```
def dupable?(obj)
  obj.class.methods.include? :new
end

dupable?(1)     # => false
dupable?(3.2)   # => false
dupable?(:a)    # => false
dupable?(true)  # => false
dupable?(nil)   # => false
dupable?("cat") # => true
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason it responds to `dup` is that Class inherits from Object which has a `dup` method.

It appears that in the `dup` method in Object checks for a 'special constant' and raises the error you're seeing:

```
VALUE
rb_obj_dup(VALUE obj)
{
    VALUE dup;

    if (rb_special_const_p(obj)) {
        rb_raise(rb_eTypeError, "can't dup %s", rb_obj_classname(obj));
    }
    dup = rb_obj_alloc(rb_obj_class(obj));
    init_copy(dup, obj);
    rb_funcall(dup, id_init_dup, 1, obj);

    return dup;
}
```

I guess the only thing you could do is check for these special constants in your method.

Answer (score 1):

There is a somewhat better way, not sure about checking error message though:

```
begin
    value = value.dup
rescue TypeError => e
    # !!! not sure about the following line
    raise unless e.message == "can't dup %s" % value.class.name
    #ignore, use the original if no dup-able (e.g nil, true, etc)
end
```