# Can I update an Active Record in an after_commit(on: :create) callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

After I create a record, I send an email, which I do in an `after_commit` callback. I want to save the `Message-Id` header of the email as an attribute on the record to use later. I implemented this as:

```
after_commit on: :create do
  if email = Mailer.email(self).deliver
    # `self.message_id = email.message_id` has no effect, so I'm calling update()
    self.update message_id: email.message_id
  end
end
```

Surprisingly (to me), this causes an infinite email-sending loop (sorry, Mailgun); it appears that the callback is called on update **even though `on: :create` is specified**.

Is there something wrong with this approach that I'm not seeing? How else could I attach this value to this record?

My only thought is to try [gating the callback on `previous_changes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128073/after-commit-for-an-attribute), but in any case I'd like to understand why this doesn't work as-is.

Comment: It occurs to me that an easier way than `previous_changes` would be to just only send the email if `message_id` isn't yet set. That would probably work, but it's still confusing to me why this doesn't work as-is.

Answer (score 7):

## "Is there something wrong with this approach that I'm not seeing?"

I would also expect `update` in `after_commit` callback to trigger only `on: update` callbacks. However I found [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/89397d09ebb7ca4089f17820d05d5eb223913652/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb#L311) in Rails source:

```
def committed!(should_run_callbacks = true) #:nodoc:
  _run_commit_callbacks if should_run_callbacks && destroyed? || persisted?
ensure
  force_clear_transaction_record_state
end
```

Only after running all after_commit callbacks does Rails clear new_record status of the transaction.

## "How else could I attach this value to this record?"

### Idea 1:

```
self.update_columns message_id: email.message_id
```

This won't create transaction and thus won't trigger another after_commit callback. I think it's appropriate to send email and store id in the record outside transaction. After all, if something fails you cannot rollback updating record with message ID *and* rollback sending email. It's just not atomic by nature.

### Idea 2:

In `after_commit` callback queue an [ActiveJob](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) job that sends email and updates record with message id. With real backend like SuckerPunch or DelayedJob the job is queued with record's "[Global ID](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#globalid)". Job's `perform` method gets a freshly loaded record with no transaction state stored in its instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
after_commit :email_send, :if => lambda{ new_record? }
```

or

```
after_commit :email_send, :on => :create
```

or

```
after_create :email_send


def email_send
    if email = Mailer.email(self).deliver
        # `self.message_id = email.message_id` has no effect, so I'm calling update()
        self.update message_id: email.message_id
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking for the prior existence of `message_id` seems to have solved the problem in my particular case:

```
after_commit on: :create do
  unless self.message_id
    if email = Mailer.email(self).deliver
      self.update message_id: email.message_id
    end
  end
end
```

But I imagine there could be a scenario where I couldn't get away with that, so it'd still be good to understand why an `on: :create` callback is being called on update.